# Adding to function pointer map in dynamic library

Tags: c++, dictionary, function-pointers, shared-libraries

The two code sections below show important info. The real work is done in the third code section, main.cpp.

```
// For all files:
typedef void (*func_ptr)(Event&); // Event is a class with certain methods
```

foo.cpp

```
extern "C" void init(std::map<std::string, func_ptr> *func_ptrs)
{
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"Initializing..."<<std::endl; // does appear in output, so function does execute
    (*func_ptrs)["test"] = stuff; // the stuff function below
}

// this is the function we are trying to add to the func_ptrs map
// It looks like it's added in main.cpp, but calling it in main.cpp seg faults
void stuff(Event &e)
{
    std::cout<<"In stuff..."<<std::endl; // seg faults before this line
    // do things with e
}
```

main.cpp

```
// Excluding fluff for brevity, use comments to understand location of problem

// In main....

map<string, func_ptr> func_ptrs; // map of strings to func_ptrs
void (*init)(map<string, func_ptr>*);
// some other stuff

handle = dlopen("libfoo.so", RLTD_NOW);
// library opens successfully

*(void **) (&init) = dlsym(handle, "init"); // get the init function from the library
// No, I don't completely understand the above sequence of pointers and reference, but it does open successfully

(*init)(&func_ptrs);
// Executes successfully

// Iterating over func_ptrs shows that the new "test" mapping is in func_ptrs!!

// Next, this should call the stuff function in foo.cpp that was assigned to func_ptrs["test"]
(func_ptrs["test"])(event); // seg fault
```

So to recap,

1. the libfoo.so library is loading properly
2. the init symbol in libfoo.so is being retrieved properly
3. the map key "test" is visible in main.cpp after libfoo's init() is run

**Error**: trying to execute libfoo's stuff, located in main.cpp's map func_ptrs, **seg faults**

Note: another option could be to give an "add to map" function to main.cpp, which libfoo.so could call to add the mapping to the list of function. Does this seem easier/better?

I was able to find a lot of similar questions/answers, but none crossed my path relating closely enough to the situation I'm dealing with. Thank you guys so much for your help, I have yet to be disappointed. Hopefully I didn't screw up shortening the code.

Comment: Just for simplicity, have you tried printing out the value of `func_ptrs["test"]`? And the address of `stuff`? Do they match?

Comment: what options did you use when build/linked libfoo.so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works with gcc version 4.7.2 20121109:

d_a.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>

class Event { 
  public: 
    void method1() { std::cout << "method1: " << name << std::endl; }
    Event(std::string& n):name(n) {}
  private: std::string name;
};
typedef void (*func_ptr)(Event&); 

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  std::string name = "Some";
  Event ev(name);
  std::map<std::string, func_ptr> func_ptrs; 
  void (*init)(std::map<std::string, func_ptr>*);
  void *handle = dlopen("./d_l.so", RTLD_NOW);
  *(void **) (&init) = dlsym(handle, "init");
  (*init)(&func_ptrs);
  (func_ptrs["test"])(ev);
  return 0;
}
```

d_l.cc:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void stuff(Event& e)
{ 
  e.method1();
  std::cout<<"In stuff..."<<std::endl; 
}

extern "C" void init(std::map<std::string, func_ptr> *func_ptrs)
{ 
  std::cout<<std::endl<<"Initializing..."<<std::endl; 
  (*func_ptrs)["test"] = stuff; 
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ d_a.cc -ldl
g++ d_l.cc -fPIC -shared -o d_l.so
```

Execute:

```
./a.out
```

Output:

```
Initializing...
method1: Some
In stuff...
```